# Batch to filter the text or number between symbols from a text file

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a text file, `file.txt`

which contains,

```
[{"84.15.160.174:4145":"178.208.17.195:9999"},
{"84.15.160.174:4145":"58.253.154.117:9999"},
{"84.15.160.174:4145":"112.87.71.194:9999"},
{"84.15.160.174:4145":"185.103.88.103:38692"}]
```

I like to filter only the IP address with port inside those " " symbols line by line in another text file called `ip.txt` . The number of ip and port i have given here is 8 is for example. It may vary by 50 to 100 also. Whatever it is, just like to filter ip&port between " " this symbols line by line (each ip port per line) will be good i guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [test.bat]

```
@echo off 
cls
FOR /F tokens^=2^,4^ delims^=^" %%a in (file.txt) do (
echo %%a
echo %%b
)
```

## [file.txt]

```
[{"84.15.160.174:4145":"178.208.17.195:9999"},
{"84.15.160.174:4145":"58.253.154.117:9999"},
{"84.15.160.174:4145":"112.87.71.194:9999"},
{"84.15.160.174:4145":"185.103.88.103:38692"}]
```

## Output:

```
84.15.160.174:4145
178.208.17.195:9999
84.15.160.174:4145
58.253.154.117:9999
84.15.160.174:4145
112.87.71.194:9999
84.15.160.174:4145
185.103.88.103:38692
```